# Is there any way to keep Developer Tools open when debugging a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, developer-tools

I'm trying to debug a Chrome Extension but every time I refresh it, the developer tools window that is associated with the extension closes. Does anyone know if there is a way to keep it open?

Here's what I'm doing: I click the extension button, which opens a popup window. I then right click it and click "Inspect". That opens the Developer Tools. Now if I click the extension button again to refresh it (when I update code), the Developer Tools closes. :(

Answer (score 63):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

- Click on the Dev Tools popup so the window is focused and then press F5. This will reload the popup and Dev Tools, and will not cause the Dev Tools window to close.
- If that doesn't work for you, go to `chrome-extension://extensionid/path/to/popup.html` on a separate tab on Chrome. From there, you can inspect element, and refreshing the file will not cause Dev Tools to close.

Comment: THIS WORKED THANKS SO MUCH OMG WTF LOL BBQ BRB INB4U AFK 9000

Comment: THANK YOU - WOW!! This was making me crazy, my dev tools window would close every time my extension popup closed. Made me crazy!!!

Comment: This must be in the official documentation.

Comment: I've found (in Chrome 71.0.3578.98, at least) that opening the background page, `chrome-extension://extensionid/_generated_background_page.html`, in another tab in addition to the popup.html tab prevents the dev tools from closing when closing the extension popup. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Man, you literally just made my life a million times better!

Comment: For Mac users, hold down CMD and press the 'R' key (worked for me at least). This should reflect any changes you've made in the code, but it won't stay if you close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Dev Tools are closing because hosted page is closing (the popup). The view and it's logic stops working if you close the popup so there's nothing to inspect.

If you'd like to debug background page it will not close with the popup since it is running in background. That's all you can do.

Comment: Yes but I then need to reload popup when code changes. So you do just keep inspecting every time you reload? That's like 10000 useless actions per day :(

Comment: I simply press F5 in devtools for the popup and it reloads it. Of course this will only work provided you change the code only in the popup. BTW consider doing minor edits to tweak/test variants right in the devtools source editor.

Comment: Hmm. As soon as I press F5 the whole page reloads and extension popup disappears and developer console disappears also. Not sure how to keep it open still. I'm starting 100 bounty. An animation/gif showing how this works would help.

Comment: F5 should be pressed in a detached devtools window.